# iOS6 NSDateFormatter default year

Tags: nsdateformatter, ios6, ios5

Has anyone noticed that iOS6 NSDateFormatter defaults to year 2000 when no year is given while in

iOS6:

[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] dateFromString: @"7:30am"]

=> 2000 Jan 1st, 7:30am

iOS5:

=> 1970 Jan 1st, 7:30am

Question:
1.  Is there a better way to compare two different times?  I have this subway app [PATH Schedule/Map](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pathway-schedule-map/id495582516?mt=8).  The subway times are hardcoded in the database as numSecondsSince1970.  I give people the next train arriving by comparing departure times with the current numSecondsSince1970.
Right now I am just appending the year 1970 to the time string "2:30am" => "1970 2:30am" but it seems like there is a better way

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I just noticed this issue. Apparently this bug is reported at Apple, see http://openradar.appspot.com/12358210

---

**Edit:** this is how I dealt with this issue in a project I'm working on...

```
// I use the following code in a category to parsing date strings

- (NSDate *)dateWithPath:(NSString *)path format:(NSString *)format
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
    formatter.dateFormat = format;

    NSString *string = [self valueWithPath:path];
    return [formatter dateFromString:string];
}
```

---

```
// old parsing code that worked fine in iOS 5, but has issues in iOS 6

NSDate *date            = [element dateWithPath:@"datum_US" format:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *timeStart       = [element dateWithPath:@"aanvang" format:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSTimeInterval interval = [timeStart timeIntervalSince1970];
match.timeStart         = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];
```

*and the fix ...*

```
// the following code works fine in both iOS 5 and iOS 6

NSDate *date                = [element dateWithPath:@"datum_US" format:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *timeStart           = [element dateWithPath:@"aanvang" format:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSCalendar *calendar        = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
calendar.timeZone           = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
NSUInteger units            = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *timeComps = [calendar components:units fromDate:timeStart];
match.timeStart             = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:timeComps toDate:date options:0];
```

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang.  I just saw this