# How to convert date to string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have string - Dec 13, 10:00 AM IST

How to convert this string to date anyone suggest ?

I created this date formatter but getting null -

```
NSDateFormatter *userTimeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[userTimeFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[userTimeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
userTimeFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;
[userTimeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far that converts your string with the dateFormatter?

Comment: That string is not enough to create a NSDate, it doesn't have a year. Where does this string come from?

Comment: That IST time zone, is it necessary or can you remove it from string and set the time manually? It will help a lot lol

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12449553/1066828 visit this link for why 2000 as year...

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *userTimeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *dateString = @"Dec 13, 10:00 AM IST";

NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"IST"];
[userTimeFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" IST" withString:@""];
[userTimeFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, hh:mm a"];

NSDate *date = [userTimeFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"india date : %@", date);
```

This will give you the IST TimeZone NSDate, from this date you can convert to system timezone with:

```
[userTimeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *myDate = [userTimeFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"my date : %@", myDate);
```

Output:

```
india date : 2000-12-13 04:30:00 +0000
my date : 2000-12-13 06:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: I don't know how to get timezone from IST instead of +0530. So if you know the answer please edit the answer.

Comment: It will post year 2000 because no year is provided in the date given. If you want current time use `[NSDate date]`

Comment: yes, I double check and gives 2000... question now is why 2000 only?

Comment: If you want correct year you should put it in the date string, unless you get the current year from `[NSDate date]` which is 2014. `Dec 13, 10:00 AM IST` has no year in the string so it will default to 2000.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12449553/1066828 visit for more info on why 2000... this is bug...